# Relative image-path in js-file and Masterpages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0, path

### Situation:

I'm using a jQuery Menu in my Masterpage. This masterpage is used for several pages in the root directory of the webapplication. Now i have a page in a sub-directory and all the image-, stlyesheet and javascript-files paths are invalid there. I solved it almost by using servercontrols, tilde(~) and adding scriptreferences to the ScriptManager as you can see here:

```
    <link runat="server" href="~/styles/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="~/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/ddsmoothmenu.css" />
    <link runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/styles/ddsmoothmenu-v.css" />
    <link runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/jQuery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager AllowCustomErrorsRedirect="true"  EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" AsyncPostBackTimeout="300" EnableScriptGlobalization="True" CombineScripts="true" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/jQuery/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/jQuery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/jQuery/js/jPrint.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/jQuery/js/ddsmoothmenu.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/jQuery/js/nav.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/CommonFunctions.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

**But i have one problem left:**

In one js-file two images of the menu are referenced by a relative path and either it's wrong on the pages in the root directory or in the page(s) in the sub-directories:

```
var ddsmoothmenu={
//Specify full URL to down and right arrow images (23 is padding-right added to top level LIs with drop downs):
arrowimages: { down: ['downarrowclass', './images/down.gif', 23], right: ['rightarrowclass', './images/right.gif'] },
transition: {overtime:300, outtime:300}, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds
shadow: {enable:true, offsetx:5, offsety:5}, //enable shadow?
showhidedelay: {showdelay: 100, hidedelay: 200}, //set delay in milliseconds before sub menus appear and disappear, respectively
```

I could use absolute paths, but that would work only on the productive system and not on the development systems. Is there no other way to handle this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using relative paths to the domain. Like `'/images/down.gif'`

Comment: Then the path could not be resolved because the webapplication-name is not part of it(`http://webserver.domain.net/images/right.gif`). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe i have missed something, but `'/images/down.gif'` will work relative to the root of the domain regardless of the domain name.

Comment: The point is: on productive server i got the img-url: `http://webserver.domain.net/images/right.gif` and on dev-systems(integrated VS Dev-Server): `http://localhost:1973/images/right.gif`. This works on dev-comp. but not on prod-server. If i precede the applicationname, it would work vice versa. Now i ended with using absolute paths what works for me.

Comment: @tim what g.foley said should work.  If i understand correctly, the master page is in the root folder, and now you have a new page in /root/subfolder1/page.aspx, is that right?  relative paths should work for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS backgrounds instead of images. That way all the image paths are relative to the STYLESHEET not the PAGE.

Comment: The js-file is thirdparty source i would unwillingly change, but i'll keep that in mind. Thanks.